# Why "cksum" is not compute in Scapy

Tags: scapy

I wrote this code in a scapy script.
The goal is to generate ICMP v6 Request and get the checksum.

```
def generate_frame():
    eth = Ether()
    eth.dst = "00:50:56:9E:7B:BB"
    eth.src = "00:50:56:9E:78:AA"
    eth.type = 0x8100
    ip = IPv6()
    ip.src = "2002:c000:0203:0000:0000:0000:0000:00AA"
    ip.dst = "2002:c000:0203:0000:0000:0000:0000:00BB"
    icmp =ICMPv6EchoRequest(seq=0x1, id=0x792)
    icmp.data = "test"
    icmp = ICMPv6EchoRequest(icmp.do_build())
    ip = IPv6(ip.do_build())
    return eth/Dot1Q(vlan=0x185)/ip/icmp

frame = generate_frame()
hexdump(frame)
#frame.pdfdump(layer_shift = 1)
frame.getlayer(ICMPv6EchoRequest).show2()
print "CRC :"+ str(frame['ICMPv6EchoRequest'].cksum)
```

I get the result :

```
0000  00 50 56 9E 7B BB 00 50 56 9E 78 AA 81 00 01 85  .PV.{..PV.x.....
0010  86 DD 60 00 00 00 00 00 3B 40 20 02 C0 00 02 03  ..`.....;@ .....
0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AA 20 02 C0 00 02 03  .......... .....
0030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BB 80 00 00 00 07 92  ................
0040  00 01 74 65 73 74                                ..test
###[ ICMPv6 Echo Request ]### 
  type      = Echo Request
  code      = 0
  cksum     = 0x0
  id        = 0x792
  seq       = 0x1
  data      = 'test'

CRC :0
```

But the **cksum** attribute still not evaluated.
I don't understand my mistake.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use the `do_build` function. It is a private function that should not be used (it is the second part of a 3-step building process).

Also, it is unnecessary to build each layer. You can just stack them and build the whole packet at the end.

To build an entire packet, call `bytes()` on it. Building a packet generates the checksums. A good option is to call `Ether(bytes(packet))` to get the packet built

Use

```
def generate_frame():    
    eth = Ether()
    eth.dst = "00:50:56:9E:7B:BB"
    eth.src = "00:50:56:9E:78:AA"
    eth.type = 0x8100
    ip = IPv6()
    ip.src = "2002:c000:0203:0000:0000:0000:0000:00AA"
    ip.dst = "2002:c000:0203:0000:0000:0000:0000:00BB"
    icmp =ICMPv6EchoRequest(seq=0x1, id=0x792)
    icmp.data = "test"
    packet = eth/Dot1Q(vlan=0x185)/ip/icmp
    # Build and recalculate the whole packet
    packet = Ether(bytes(packet))
    return packet
```

It should fix your issue

[image: Corrected code result]